# nginx: set default behavour for all sites?

Tags: nginx

I want to have these rules on ALL sites. I just have no idea how to do it.

```
location = /favicon.ico {
    expires 168h;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
    #return 404;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    expires 168h;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /someotherlocation.ext {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.
Workaround: move these settings to a separate file and include it in every server.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a file and `include` this file in all your virtual host.